# PHP can not resolve mysql container name under certain circumstances

Tags: mysql, docker, hostname

I have legacy PHP application. It used mysqli to make mysql things. So in config I have DSN string to connect to mysql service. Like that

`mysql://username:password@db_hostname/dbname`

Mysqli returns error

**Warning: mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known**

But if I will try connect by hand using this

`mysqli::real_connect("db_hostname")`

It says **Warning: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'172.21.0.3' (using password: NO)**

`real_connect("user@db_hostname")`, `real_connect("mysql:db_hostname")`, `real_connect("mysql:host=db_hostname")` can not resolve host address.

What I'm doing wrong?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./docker/nginx/errors.log:/var/logs/errors.log
      - ./docker/nginx/access.log:/var/logs/access.log
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker/
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
    user: "1000"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/timezone.php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/timezone.php.ini:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ./:/var/www/html

  db_hostname:
    image: mysql:5.5
    user: "1000"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Comment: Are you using a docker-compose.yml config file? Can you please provide that?

Comment: @Chrysovalantis Koutsoumpos added

Comment: Host address seems good. I think that you are somehow not passing the password. Checking out the mysqli::real_connect documentation I see that you have to connect like this real_connect::real_connect('db_hostname', 'user', 'user', 'db')
Did you tried this? Try also with the root credentials. Also did you tried to access it from outside the app, fe from SequelPro?

Comment: And try to expose the port in db_hostname service. 
ports:
- "3306:3306"

Comment: On the dev and prod servers it works with DSN connection string only. Like this one - `mysq://user:pass@host/dbname`. But within the docker container it can not resolve host, but host is reachable using `gethostbyname` for example. It is unresolveable using DSN, why?

Comment: I think this is the normal docker behaviour. You can configure host settings in docker containers or introduce a reverse proxy (traefik) in order to set frontend and backend host names. For the first option you just need to set a hostname: db_hostname below image: mysql:5:5. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you missing **linking** you db container with php. When you link db with PHP it will be accessible from localhost of PHP.

Here is I modified your docker-compose file as I like alpine everywhere ;). And I use adminer and link with db to verfiy connection instead of code level checking. As i dont have you php docker file so i am creating php:alpine which contain php7.

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
  db:
    image: mysql:5.5
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  php:
    image: php:alpine
    container_name: php
    tty: true
    links:
     - db 
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: adminer
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
     - db
```

Then i installed mysqli in php container

```
docker exec -it php ash
```

and run below command

```
docker-php-ext-install mysqli;
```

Then create test.php

here server name is **db**. Note that your server name will be what is db container name which is link to php.
if you `ping db` in php container it will ping db container.

```
    <?php
$servername = "db";
$username = "root";
$password = "example";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Now run this file in php container. You can mount and run your php code but this is what I did for testing. And I tried as a root user.

```
php -f test.php
```

[image]

And here is adminer which also link with db

[image]

[image]

Comment: big thanks to you... I spent two days trying to figure out the issue but finally, your answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose rm -v` use and delete MySQL volume.

Volumes:

- `./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -> pathmysql`
- `/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro`
- `/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro`