# use two web api projects with different connection strings with docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose

I have a solution with 2 web api projects and a web application project which calls api controller methods from those two. How do I configure and use use yml file in order to do this.

[image]

*docker-compose.override.yml* is as follows

```
version: '3'

services:
  twobatch:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"

  newpost.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionString=Data Source=DESKTOP-QVMU6HA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbpractice;Integrated Security=True
    ports:
      - "80"

  webapplication1:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"
    depends_on:
      - twobatch
      - newpost.api
```

What should I do to access this connection string from the web api project?

thanks

Comment: Do you want to use the same `ConnectionString` in both containers?

Comment: use docker linking, link web application to API both container so both will be accessible as a localhost  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342027/3288890

Comment: @Andremonly no 2 different connection strings for 2 different web api projects. I want to know how do I access the connection string from the web api projects so that I can connect to the database and get some values to display on a web page.