# Django app in Docker container unable to find postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab-ci

I have a Django application on gitlab and I am trying to add CI/CD using gitlab-ci. I started a server on EC2 and installed gitlab-runner on it.

I added `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to my project and pushed the latest changes. I can see the pipeline running and dependencies being installed. But When the script tries to run tests, I get an error like this:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused
>
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Below is my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` script:

```
image: python:3-jessie

services:
  - postgres:latest

before_script:
  - python -V
  - apt-get -y update
  - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install --upgrade pip

stages:
  - build

build:
  type: build
  variables:
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/opensys_erp
  script:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python manage.py test
  only:
  - branches
```

Why is my application unable to connect to postgres server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your container try to connect postgres on their own localhost that's why you getting connection refused. `127.0.0.1` this localhost is the localhost of `Django application` container. To connect with postgress using localhost you need to **link** your docker container.

> Docker also has a linking system that allows you to link multiple containers together and send connection information from one to another. When containers are linked, information about a source container can be sent to a recipient container.

**How services are linked to the job**

> To summarize, if you add mysql as service to your application, the image will then be used to create a container that is **linked** to the job container.
>
> The service container for MySQL will be accessible under the hostname
>   mysql. So, in order to access your database service you have to
>   connect to the host named mysql instead of a socket or localhost.

A day before I post a detailed answer for the same sort of question you check this as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342027/3288890

You can check some links

https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services

Comment: Thanks it worked.. But there is a slight issue. My application is a django project and on local I use the host as `localhost`. Is there any way I can map the localhost in my settings file to `postgres` in '.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: yes if you link your contianer you will use the contianer name as host. for example you link php with db and the mysql contianer name is db then your localhost will longer need you can use db which will point to your contianer of mysql. if exec in container will see entry of db in php container etc/hosts where db will point to mysql contianer with thier docker netwrok ip.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) correct, you should remove the `:` after the `postgres` user:

`postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]`

So your string would be:

`postgres://postgres@postgres:5432/opensys_erp`

Comment: And your application is reading the `DATABASE_URL` correctly?